# Dual Booting NixOS and Windows 10. Can it be done easily if NixOS is installed first?

Tags: dual-boot, nixos

I have an SSD with NixOS installed on it and an HDD that is currently a LUKS encrypted data store. I want to put Windows 10 on part of the HDD.

Since I've already installed NixOS, does this work.

Usually, when I've done dual boots I remember installing Windows first.

I plan on referencing this.

https://nixos.wiki/wiki/Dual_Booting_NixOS_and_Windows

Thanks.

Comment: In the past with BIOS/MBR systems what would happen is Windows would override the Linux bootloader, which would have to be restored after the fact to boot Linux. With UEFI systems the same could happen, but tools like `efibootmgr` can be used change the default bootmanager back to `systemd-boot`. I had trouble setting the default on my system (Dell Latitude) so I installed rEFInd.

Answer (score 2):

You could install Windows and allow it to overwrite your boot partition.
Then you could use a NixOS live-cd to reinstall your NixOS bootloader.
Therefore first mount your system as you have done for installation to `/mnt`. Then run `nixos-install` again. Running `nixos-install` is idempotent so your nixos install is not in danger - your system will be re-installed based on your configuration.nix. After that you should be able to append the windows bootloader as described in the [wiki](https://nixos.wiki/wiki/Dual_Booting_NixOS_and_Windows)